# How do I get a domain like bit.ly and goog.gl?

Tags: domains

Where do i can buy/rent domain just like bit.ly, goog.gl, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You can use domai.nr to search and link to the correct registrar

[Domainr: fast, free, domain name search, short URLs, international domain registration](http://domai.nr/)

[image: domai.nr]